# how to add jqxEditorModule in angular 8

Tags: jquery, angular, import, html-editor, jqwidget

I am trying to implement Angular HTML Editor by following this link here: [https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular/angular-editor/angular-editor-defaultfunctionality.htm](http://Angular%20Editor%20Default%20Functionality)

But I'm getting error on:

```
import * as jqxEditorModule from 'jqwidgets-ng/jqxeditor'
```

Here is the reference screenshot of the code and error:

[image]

I have downloaded `jqwidgets` and also pasted in `nodemodules` as well.
I have also run the following commands for installation:

```
npm install jqwidgets-scripts --save
npm info jqwidgets-framework
```

But I'm still getting error.

Comment: have you tried with import  * as jqxEditorModule from 'jqwidgets-ng/jqxeditor'

Comment: in your code you also missed the word .. FROM .. so try also import {jqxEditorModule} from 'jqwidgets-ng/jqxeditor'

Comment: from keyword is used also changed as 
import * as jqxEditorModule from  'jqwidgets-ng/jqxeditor'

Comment: i have attached error image please suggest

Comment: try with import {jqxEditorModule} from 'jqwidgets-ng'

Comment: or import jqxEditorModule from 'jqwidgets-ng/jqxeditor'

Comment: check this guide ..your using worng package i think... https://github.com/jqwidgets/create-jqwidgets-angular-app

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this: [jqxEditor for Angular Docs](https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular-components-documentation/documentation/jqxeditor/angular-editor-getting-started.htm)? It shows how to get started with the jqxEditorComponent and import it.